# How to access to repository file with GIT in post-receive hook

Tags: git, git-post-receive

I have this scenario with GIT:

I want to "do something" with a specific file when it is changed in a push.
For example a .sql file must be dumped in a db if it's changed.

I'm using 'post-receive' hook in GIT with a statement like this:

```shell
DUMP=$(git diff-tree --name-only -r -z master dump.sql);

if [ -n "$DUMP" ]; then
  // using the new dump.sql
fi
```

How can I access to the new dump.sql just pushed from the hook?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can retrieve file dump.sql from revision $rev using:

```
git cat-file blob $rev:dump.sql
```

The post-receive hook is also called for things other than pushing master... hopefully you have a check somewhere that you're processing the updated master ref. As a matter of style, I'd use the new-revision value passed to the hook rather than referencing master directly from within the hook.

Usually I write a post-receive hook like this:

```
while read oldrev newrev refname; do
    if [ "$refname" = "refs/heads/master" ]; then
        # definitely updating master; $oldrev and $newrev encompass the changes
        if git diff-tree --name-only -r -z $oldrev $newrev dump.sql; then
            # dump.sql changed...
        fi
    fi
done
```

Importantly, this also copes with a single push sending over several commits to master in one go--- the command you showed in the question only looked at the last commit on master.

Comment: Thank you very much! is there a way to be sure that the referred "branch" updated is master instead of any other branch?

Comment: @Randomize The post-receive hook is passed some information on stdin... I'll illustrate by editing the answer, it'll be more readable

Comment: WOW! thanks again! last question: googling I found docs about writing hooks too generic. Do you know any good site or book that explains properly how to write a hook, environment variables defined etc?

Comment: I don't know any documentation other than the githooks manpage, part of the standard reference documentation. To be honest, I've mostly learned about them from looking through examples-- post-receive and pre-receive are the most popular, since they're used as the equivalent of server-side triggers that other systems have. So examples like post-receive-email and various access-control pre-receive scripts are useful.

Comment: there should be: `if git diff-tree --name-only -r -z $oldrev $newrev -- dump.sql; then` or you may get "fatal: ambiguous argument..." error .